# gulp.spritesmith to supress "icon-" prefix in the generated css file

Tags: gulp, grunt-spritesmith

I am using gulp.spritesmith to automate sprite image and css generation. All works good except the generated css is haivng "icon-" prefix. I don't want to add this prefix as I have existing HTML markup and I don't want to change the markup. 
Following is my gulp task.

```
'use strict';
var gulp = require('gulp');
var spritesmith = require('gulp.spritesmith');


gulp.task('sprite', function () {    

    var spriteData =
            gulp.src('./sprite/*.*') // source path of the sprite images
            .pipe(spritesmith({
                imgName: 'sprite.png',
                cssName: 'sprite.css'
            }));

    spriteData.img.pipe(gulp.dest("./css")); // output path for the sprite
    spriteData.css.pipe(gulp.dest("./css")); // output path for the CSS
});
```

Following is my generated css.

```
.icon-icon1 {
  background-image: url(sprite.png);
  background-position: 0px 0px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
}
.icon-icon2 {
  background-image: url(sprite.png);
  background-position: -120px 0px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
}
```

Please help to supress "icon-".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [gulp-replace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-replace) to remove the "icon-" prefixes.

Last line of your `sprite` task would become

```
spriteData.css
  .pipe(replace(/^\.icon-/gm, '.'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest("./css"));
```

Comment: Thanks. Good to know about replace module. it worked. I have also tried following option which worked too cssOpts: {
                        cssSelector: function (sprite) {                            
                            return '.' + sprite.name;
                        }
                    }

Answer (score 27):

You can alternatively use the `cssSelector` of the library.

```
cssOpts: {
  cssSelector: function (sprite) {
    return '.' + sprite.name;
  }
}
```

Comment: I feel like this should be the preferred answer. Much nicer way of handling that via configuration options.